# RadioButtonList value is null

Tags: asp.net, webforms

I am building an a website for multiple choices.
My page contains two RadioButtonLists that I generate when the page is loaded.
However, when I choose item, and click the button, the selectedItem has null values. This is my code:

```
public partial class WebForm1 : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    MultipleChoiceDbContext db = new MultipleChoiceDbContext();
    List<string> questionList = new List<string>();
    List<RadioButtonList> optionList = new List<RadioButtonList>();
    List<string> answerList = new List<string>();
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            var query = from data in db.QAs
                        select data;
            QA question;

            int i = 1;
            ListItem liA;
            ListItem liB;
            ListItem liC;
            ListItem liD;
            while (i < 3)
            {
                question = query.ToList()[(new Random()).Next(query.ToList().Count)];
                questionList.Add(question.Question);
                answerList.Add(question.Answer);

                liA = new ListItem(question.A, question.A);
                liB = new ListItem(question.B, question.B);
                liC = new ListItem(question.C, question.C);
                liD = new ListItem(question.D, question.D);

                RadioButtonList rdl = new RadioButtonList();
                rdl.Items.Add(liA);
                rdl.Items.Add(liB);
                rdl.Items.Add(liC);
                rdl.Items.Add(liD);

                optionList.Add(rdl);
                phContent.Controls.Add(rdl);

                i++;
            }
        }
    }
    protected void btnok_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < optionList.Count; i++)
        {
            string content = "";
            content += optionList[i].SelectedItem.Value + "<br />";
            Response.Write(content);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You always have to re-create dynamically created controls, on every postback, in `Page_Init` or (latest) `Page_Load` with the same ID's as before. **Also**: even all objects that you have created (so your lists) are disposed at the end of the page's lifecycle when the HTML was sent to the client.

Comment: So, how can I solve this problem ?

Comment: Why do you need to create it dynamically at all, why can't you use a gridview or repeater? Why do you need to store them in that list, you can get them with `var rbs = phContent.Controls.OfType<RadioButtonList>().ToList()`. If you use a GridView or Repeater you have to loop the `gridView.Rows` or `repeater.Items` and use `row.FindControl("RadioButtonListID")`.

Comment: This is the first way I got when I come with the problem. So I can try to do it myself.
And where the var rbs = phContent.Controls.OfType<RadioButtonList>().ToList() place ?

Comment: Where you want to get all your `RadioButtonList`s and if you keep the dynamic approach without using a webdatabound control like `Repeater`.

Comment: I had added into the first line of button click function.
However, it returns a empty list .

Comment: That's because you haven't re-created the dynamical controls on postback, what i've mentioned in my first comment and why i suggested to use a webdatabound control ;)

Comment: So, how can I re-create the dynamical controls on postback ?
I want to complete my way first, then I can do other thing.

Comment: Create a method `DataBindQuestions` and add the code above. Then remove the `!IsPostBack`-check and do that on every postback. Note that your query is very inefficient. Why don't you create a random  list at the beginning? You could use `var rndList = query.OrderBy(q => Guid.NewGuid()).ToList()`. Then you just need to loop this list.

Comment: `DataBindQuestions` method contains only `var rbs = phContent.Controls.OfType<RadioButtonList>().ToList();` statement ?
And how can I check on every postback ?

Comment: No, that method is used to fill the `PlaceHolder` with the `RadioButtonList`. Wherever you want to get those rbl's later (f.e. in the button-click event handler) you can use `...Controls.OfType<RadioButtonList>...`.

Comment: I will try it several more times.
Thank you so much

Comment: I have got the value of radioButtonList.
But I had new problem: when I refresh the page, all questions are the same as them before.
How can I create new question list when the page loaded ?